# drop-area element not hiding with DND module and FineUploaderBasic

Tags: fine-uploader

I've got everything working well except the drop area element doesn't hide after moving back off the page.

For example, if I drag something to the page, the drop area element shows, but then if I decide not to drop, it stays visible instead of hiding. It looks like in the demos on the site, it should hide again.

I've been studying this page: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/options/fineuploader.html#draganddrop-option-properties

There doesn't seem to be a callback for when there is no longer a file about to be dropped in the browser window. My code looks just like the examples, but has my own element id and class names, both of which work.

Any ideas?

**Update** - here is some code:

```
<div id="file-upload-well" class="well text-center">
    <div id="file-upload-drop-area" style="display:none;">Drop files here</div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Upload Files</a>
</div>
```

and here is the DND js:

```
var dragAndDropModule = new qq.DragAndDrop({
dropZoneElements: [document.getElementById('file-upload-drop-area')],
classes: {
    dropActive: "dropActive"
},
callbacks: {
    processingDroppedFiles: function () {
        $('#file-upload-drop-area').hide();
    },
    processingDroppedFilesComplete: function(files) {
        uploader.addFiles(files); 
    }
}
});
```

Comment: *I'm using fineuploader 3.7

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Latest build of Chrome

Comment: Latest build on which channel in which OS?  I'm using the latest build on the beta channel on OS X, and am not seeing this issue.

Comment: Latest build of the stable channel on mac. Also seeing the same thing with FF 22 on mac.

Comment: Here's my drop area code:
`<div id="file-upload-drop-area" style="display:none;"><span class="lead muted">Drop files here</span></div>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are showing me exactly.  Please edit your question and provide all of your client-side code, including relevant HTML.

Comment: Updated with some code. To be clear as well: the #file-upload-drop-area stays hidden until I start dragging a file over the browser. Then it shows with a `display:block`. Then when I go back and put the file down (not dropping on the page), it stays as `display:block;`

Comment: You are looking at the wrong documentation page.  See the `hideDropZonesBeforeEnter` option on the [standalone drag-and-drop module documentation page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/drag-and-drop.html).  Also, I assume you are using FineUploaderBasic, otherwise you should not be using this standalone module.

Comment: Correct: FineUploaderBasic is what is being used. I was looking at that page, but must've copied the wrong link.

`hideDropZonesBeforeEnter` was the option I was looking for, however the documentation makes it sound like the dropbox will only show when something is being hovered over the drop area, not when a file is being hovered over the entire browser page. All good now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer, and then accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was setting the `hideDropZonesBeforeEnter` is set to `false` by default and needed to be set to true.

Both the variable name and the help documentation make it seem it will only show the drop zone when a file is directly over it, but instead it hides and shows the dropdown when a file is over a compliant browser.

Comment: I'll include a clarification in the next version's documentation.